# Spark dataframe join aggregating by ID

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have problem in joining 2 dataframes grouped by ID

```scala
val df1 = Seq(
    (1, 1,100),
    (1, 3,20),
    (2, 5,5),
    (2, 2,10)).toDF("id", "index","value")

  val df2 = Seq(
    (1, 0),
    (2, 0),
    (3, 0),
    (4, 0),
    (5,0)).toDF("index", "value")
```

df1 joins with df2 by index column for every id

expected result

| id | index | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 20 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 5 |

please help me on this

Comment: Can you share your join statement? What you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would replace your `df2` table with this:

```
var df2 = Seq(
  (Array(1, 2), Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
).toDF("id", "index")
```

This allows us to use `explode` and auto-generate a table which can be of help to us:

```
df2 = df2
  .withColumn("id", explode(col("id")))
  .withColumn("index", explode(col("index")))
```

and it gives:

```
+---+-----+
|id |index|
+---+-----+
|1  |1    |
|1  |2    |
|1  |3    |
|1  |4    |
|1  |5    |
|2  |1    |
|2  |2    |
|2  |3    |
|2  |4    |
|2  |5    |
+---+-----+
```

Now, all we need to do, is `join` with your `df1` as below:

```
df2 = df2
  .join(df1, Seq("id", "index"), "left")
  .withColumn("value", when(col("value").isNull, 0).otherwise(col("value")))
```

And we get this final output:

```
+---+-----+-----+
|id |index|value|
+---+-----+-----+
|1  |1    |100  |
|1  |2    |0    |
|1  |3    |20   |
|1  |4    |0    |
|1  |5    |0    |
|2  |1    |0    |
|2  |2    |10   |
|2  |3    |0    |
|2  |4    |0    |
|2  |5    |5    |
+---+-----+-----+
```

which should be what you want. Good luck!